# Beginning a blank web role project in Azure?

Tags: windows, azure

sorry if this seems really dumb, I'm totally new to .NET.  The problem I seem to have is when starting a new 'cloud' project in VS2010 and including a web role within it, it seems to create a default project with a number of .apsx pages etc.  The project is a basic looking 'welcome to asp .net' website.  Is there a way to get rid of this so I don't have to work out which files to delete so I can start fresh each time without all this guff.

I am using Windows Azure SDK 1.3, although it was the case in 1.2 also.  Sorry again if I am being really stupid here, I've been searching how to create a blank project to no avail.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select to not add a web role and instead add a web app. The web app should be added directly to the cloud service. Then, you can start adding in the Azure related components you need for the hosted version of your web app (storage, diagnostics, etc...).

While this still doesn't give you a "blank" project (the adding of basic files in applies to all the VS project templates), it does further minimize the amount of extra files/settings that are being imported. Its also a useful approach when you're wanting to deploy a existing web app to Azure with minimal modification.

To do this:
1) file -> new -> cloud service (click ok all the way through without adding any roles)
2) right click the solution, select add, and add a new web app project (not web site)
3) right click the "roles" folder in the cloud service project and select add -> Web Role Project in solution.
4) select the web app you added in step 2

Out of curiousity, why do you want a "blank" project? Just so you can plug your stuff in without having to remove anything?

Comment: Thanks man I really appreciate the answer, I will give this a shot.  I have a few basic ASP tuts laying about that I wanted to try and port to Azure.  As I say I'm new to it, so just learning through trial and error.

Comment: i came here to ask the same question. the stuff that microsoft throws in to 'help' is to much :P it ads like 20+ packages just by creating the role. this was a great answer. thank you!